# How did you get the name of owner of github repo?

Tags: github

i'm a contributor and need to use the github API " GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:sha " . couldn't figure out who the owner is . Please share the procedure to find out the owner.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the github.com version of the repo (so not using api.github.com) you can see the owner to the left below the logo.
On the same page you can also see the name of a repo
this results (for one of mine) in https://api.github.com/repos/sergefonville/JavaScript this outputs the relevant information

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For an Enterprise user viewing a repo in github.com, the owner is the Organization that the repo sits under.
For instance if you have an Organisation called CloudServices, with a repo called migration-portal. The url path to the repo becomes https://github.com/CloudServices/migration-portal. So the

- repo is migration-portal
- owner is CloudServices, the Organization that the repo belongs to